# How to generate a boxplot of two groups that measure the same variable?

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to generate a side-by-side boxplot of income between USA and JAPAN, both of which are under the third column, V#. The first column, V1, is the income variable.

I am pasting the dput output of my data.frame object.

```
structure(list(V1 = c(5252525L, 4545352L, 4242424L, 5235252L, 
5353532L, 5234242L, 5252525L, 4535352L, 5774636L, 9743643L, 2342553L, 
5352323L), V2 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
8L), V3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("CHINA", "JAPAN", "USA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I don't want China to be inlcuded in the boxplot. How can I do this??

Thanks much in advance!!

Comment: Your question is really about `factor` variables, subsetting and dropping unused levels. You should look at `?subset` and `?droplevels`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boxplot(V1 ~ factor(V3), data=dat[ dat$V3 != "CHINA", ] )
```

If you want to reduce the number of levels in a subset-ed factor variable you need to re-factor it. You can do it in this instance in the formula spec.

Comment: given that my datafile's name is USA, I tried: boxplot(V1 ~ factor(V3), data=dat[ USA$V3 != "CHINA", ] ), but I get an error message saying "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat' not found". So when I changed the command to: boxplot(V1 ~ factor(V3), data=data[ USA$V3 != "CHINA", ] ), I get another error saying:"
Error in data[USA$V3 != "CHINA", ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: am I missing something here? I'm trying to remove China from the dataframe so I can just compare USA and Japan

Comment: Replace `dat` with `USA` everywhere. i.e. `boxplot(V1 ~ factor(V3), data=USA[ USA$V3 != "CHINA", ] )`

Comment: If you do not indicate a name for your dataframe in your question, I'm free to call it anything I like. I picked "dat".

Comment: one last question if you don't mind!! if I were to include China, would I run: boxplot(V1 ~ factor(V3), data=USA[ USA$V3, ] )   ??

Comment: Could just use : `boxplot(V1 ~ V1, data=USA)` (and do not think your version would work.)

Answer (score 1):

Using droplevels and subset and assuming your data is called `dat`

```
boxplot(V1~droplevels(V3),subset(dat, V3 != 'CHINA'))
```

Note that `droplevels.factor(x,...)` simply calls `factor(x,...)` so @Dwins solution is cleaner. Specifically calling `droplevels` *may* help with readability.

You can also apply `droplevels` to a data.frame, which will drop unused levels from each factor variable

```
boxplot(V1 ~ V3, droplevels(subset(dat, V3 != 'CHINA')))
```

Comment: Yes. It certainly is. But it's also good to know how other aspects. I thought I could use drop=TRUE in "[" but came up short. `droplevels` is new but does seem to be a useful addition.

Comment: I also thought I could use `drop = T` in `subset` and failed for the same reasons.

Comment: There is a way to use `droplevels` with subset -- `droplevels.data.frame` (D'Oh!)